# How to use custom axis type? (Java)

Tags: java, function, graph, awt, axis

I would like to develop a desktop application which is able to draw a given function's graph but in a coordinate-system with custom axises. 
E.g.: user can change between linear, logarithmic, exponential etc.. axis types in case of both X and Y axis.

- Do you think that Java AWT is suitable to this purpose? (I don't know yet),
- Do you have any idea what other technologies can/should be used?
- In this case time is the most important, so I need the simplest way..

Thank you in advance,
Marton

Answer (score 0):

Swing or JavaFX would be better than AWT.

Here's some code I developed to lay a Cartesian and / or Polar coordinate system on a Swing drawing area.  You can use this as a starting point for what you want to do.

### CoordinateSystem class

```
package com.ggl.game.utilities;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * <p>
 * This class creates a Cartesian and Polar coordinate system to overlay a Swing
 * drawing area (usually a <code>JPanel</code>). The user of the class sets a
 * limit as to how far the X axis or the Y axis extends in the negative and
 * positive direction from (0, 0). Point (0, 0) will be placed in the center of
 * the drawing area.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Since the drawing area is usually not square, the limit applies to the
 * shorter dimension. The actual limits can be retrieved from this class, and
 * will change if the user of the application changes the drawing area size by
 * maximizing or normalizing the application <code>JFrame</code> window.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Using a Cartesian or Polar coordinate system frees the user of this class
 * from having to worry about Swing pixel coordinates.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author Gilbert G. Le Blanc
 * @version 1.0 - 23 February 2015
 * 
 * @see com.ggl.game.utilities.Polar2D
 * @see java.awt.geom.Point2D
 * @see javax.swing.JFrame
 * @see javax.swing.JPanel
 */
public class CoordinateSystem {

    private double conversionFactor;
    private double xLimit;
    private double yLimit;

    private int height;
    private int width;

    /**
     * <p>
     * This creates a Cartesian and Polar coordinate system over a Swing drawing
     * area (usually a <code>JPanel</code>). If the drawing area is square, the
     * X axis extends from -limit to limit and the Y axis extends from -limit to
     * limit.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * If the drawing area is not square, then the smaller dimension, either X
     * or Y, extends from -limit to limit. The larger dimension extends beyond
     * the limit in both directions.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Since most displays are not square, the X and Y axis will usually have
     * different limits.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param limit
     *            - The limit of the X and Y axis in a Cartesian coordinate
     *            system.
     * @param width
     *            - The width of the drawing area in pixels.
     * @param height
     *            - The height of the drawing area in pixels.
     */
    public CoordinateSystem(double limit, int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        if (width > height) {
            this.xLimit = limit * width / height;
            this.yLimit = limit;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) height;
        } else if (width < height) {
            this.xLimit = limit;
            this.yLimit = limit * height / width;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) width;
        } else {
            this.xLimit = limit;
            this.yLimit = limit;
            this.conversionFactor = (limit + limit) / (double) width;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method changes the drawing area dimension, along with the X and Y
     * axis limits.
     * 
     * @param dimension
     *            - A <code>Dimension</code> with the new drawing area
     *            dimension.
     */
    public void setDrawingSize(Dimension dimension) {
        setDrawingSize(dimension.width, dimension.height);
    }

    /**
     * This method changes the drawing area width and height, along with the X
     * and Y axis limits.
     * 
     * @param width
     *            - The width of the drawing area in pixels.
     * @param height
     *            - The height of the drawing area in pixels.
     */
    public void setDrawingSize(int width, int height) {
        xLimit = xLimit / this.width * width;
        yLimit = yLimit / this.height * height;

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the Cartesian coordinate limit for the X axis.
     * 
     * @return The Cartesian coordinate limit for the X axis.
     */
    public double getxLimit() {
        return xLimit;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the Cartesian coordinate limit for the Y axis.
     * 
     * @return The Cartesian coordinate limit for the Y axis.
     */
    public double getyLimit() {
        return yLimit;
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Polar coordinate distance and theta angle in
     * radians to a pixel location on a drawing area.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            - A Polar coordinate distance
     * @param theta
     *            - A Polar coordinate theta angle in radians
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertPolarToPixels(double distance, double theta) {
        return convertToPixels(new Polar2D.Double(distance, theta));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Cartesian coordinate x and y to a pixel location
     * on a drawing area.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate x.
     * @param y
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate y.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertPointToPixels(double x, double y) {
        return convertToPixels(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Polar coordinate to a pixel location on a drawing
     * area.
     * 
     * @param polar
     *            - A Polar coordinate.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertToPixels(Polar2D polar) {
        double x = polar.getDistance() * Math.cos(polar.getTheta());
        double y = polar.getDistance() * Math.sin(polar.getTheta());
        return convertToPixels(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a Cartesian coordinate to a pixel location on a
     * drawing area.
     * 
     * @param cartesian
     *            - A Cartesian coordinate.
     * @return A pixel location on a drawing area.
     */
    public Point convertToPixels(Point2D cartesian) {
        int x = (int) Math
                .round((cartesian.getX() + xLimit) / conversionFactor);
        int y = (int) Math.round((-cartesian.getY() + yLimit)
                / conversionFactor);
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Cartesian
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - The x pixel location.
     * @param y
     *            - The y pixel location.
     * @return A Cartesian coordinate.
     */
    public Point2D convertToCartesian(int x, int y) {
        return convertToCartesian(new Point(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Cartesian
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param point
     *            - The pixel location.
     * @return A Cartesian coordinate.
     */
    public Point2D convertToCartesian(Point point) {
        double x = (double) point.x * conversionFactor - xLimit;
        double y = (double) -point.y * conversionFactor + yLimit;
        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Polar
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param x
     *            - The x pixel location.
     * @param y
     *            - The y pixel location.
     * @return A Polar coordinate.
     */
    public Polar2D convertToPolar(int x, int y) {
        return convertToPolar(new Point(x, y));
    }

    /**
     * This method converts a pixel location on a drawing area to a Polar
     * coordinate.
     * 
     * @param point
     *            - The pixel location.
     * @return A Polar coordinate.
     */
    public Polar2D convertToPolar(Point point) {
        double x = (double) point.x * conversionFactor - xLimit;
        double y = (double) -point.y * conversionFactor + yLimit;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double theta = Math.atan2(y, x);
        return new Polar2D.Double(distance, theta);
    }

}
```

### Polar2D class

```
package com.ggl.game.utilities;

/**
 * The <code>Polar2D</code> class defines a point representing a location in
 * distance, theta angle coordinate space.
 * <p>
 * This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D
 * coordinate. The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to
 * the subclass.
 * 
 * @version 1.0 - 23 February 2015
 * @author Jim Graham (author of Point2D), Gilbert Le Blanc
 */
public abstract class Polar2D implements Cloneable {
    /**
     * The <code>Float</code> class defines a point specified in float
     * precision.
     */
    public static class Float extends Polar2D {
        /**
         * The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public float distance;
        /**
         * The theta angle of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public float theta;

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with coordinates
         * (0,&nbsp;0).
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Float() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with the specified
         * coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set the newly constructed
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set the newly
         *            constructed <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Float(float distance, float theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getDistance() {
            return (double) distance;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getTheta() {
            return (double) theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getThetaInDegrees() {
            double degrees = 180D / Math.PI * theta;
            return (degrees < 0D) ? degrees + 360D : degrees;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>double</code> distance and theta angle in radians.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public void setLocation(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = (float) distance;
            this.theta = (float) theta;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>float</code> coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public void setLocation(float distance, float theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a <code>String</code> that represents the value of this
         * <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @return A <code>String</code> representation of this
         *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Polar2D.Float[" + distance + ", " + theta + "]";
        }
    }

    /**
     * The <code>Double</code> class defines a point specified in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     */
    public static class Double extends Polar2D {
        /**
         * The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public double distance;
        /**
         * The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public double theta;

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with (0,&nbsp;0)
         * distance and theta angle in radians.
         * 
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Double() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructs and initializes a <code>Polar2D</code> with the specified
         * coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set the newly constructed
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set the newly
         *            constructed <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        public Double(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getTheta() {
            return theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
         * <code>double</code> precision.
         * 
         * @return The theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public double getThetaInDegrees() {
            double degrees = 180D / Math.PI * theta;
            return (degrees < 0D) ? degrees + 360D : degrees;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
         * <code>double</code> coordinates.
         * 
         * @param distance
         *            The distance to which to set this <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @param theta
         *            The theta angle in radians to which to set this
         *            <code>Polar2D</code>
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public void setLocation(double distance, double theta) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.theta = theta;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a <code>String</code> that represents the value of this
         * <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * 
         * @return A <code>String</code> representation of this
         *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
         * @since 1.7
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Polar2D.Double[" + distance + ", " + theta + "]";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is an abstract class that cannot be instantiated directly.
     * Type-specific implementation subclasses are available for instantiation
     * and provide a number of formats for storing the information necessary to
     * satisfy the various accessor methods below.
     * 
     * @see java.awt.geom.Polar2D.Float
     * @see java.awt.geom.Polar2D.Double
     * @see java.awt.Point
     */
    protected Polar2D() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance of this <code>Polar2D</code> in <code>double</code>
     * precision.
     * 
     * @return The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getDistance();

    /**
     * Returns the theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     * 
     * @return The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getTheta();

    /**
     * Returns the theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code> in
     * <code>double</code> precision.
     * 
     * @return The theta angle in degrees of this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract double getThetaInDegrees();

    /**
     * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the specified
     * <code>double</code> coordinates.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public abstract void setLocation(double distance, double theta);

    /**
     * Sets the location of this <code>Polar2D</code> to the same coordinates as
     * the specified <code>Polar2D</code> object.
     * 
     * @param p
     *            the specified <code>Polar2D</code> the which to set this
     *            <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public void setLocation(Polar2D p) {
        setLocation(p.getDistance(), p.getTheta());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance between two points.
     * 
     * @param distance1
     *            The distance of the first point
     * @Parm theta1 The theta angle in radians of the first point
     * @param distance2
     *            The distance of the second point
     * @param theta2
     *            The theta angle in radians of the second point
     * @return The square of the distance between the two specified points.
     */
    public static double distanceSq(double distance1, double theta1,
            double distance2, double theta2) {
        double x1 = distance1 * Math.cos(theta1);
        double y1 = distance1 * Math.sin(theta1);
        double x2 = distance2 * Math.cos(theta2);
        double y2 = distance2 * Math.sin(theta2);
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance between two points.
     * 
     * @param distance1
     *            The distance of the first point
     * @param theta1
     *            The theta angle in radians of the first point
     * @param distance2
     *            The distance of the second point
     * @param theta2
     *            The theta angle in radians of the second point
     * @return The distance between the two specified points.
     */
    public static double distance(double distance1, double theta1,
            double distance2, double theta2) {
        double x1 = distance1 * Math.cos(theta1);
        double y1 = distance1 * Math.sin(theta1);
        double x2 = distance2 * Math.cos(theta2);
        double y2 = distance2 * Math.sin(theta2);
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     * specified point.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of the specified point
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of the specified point
     * @return The square of the distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and
     *         the specified point.
     */
    public double distanceSq(double distance, double theta) {
        double x1 = distance * Math.cos(theta);
        double y1 = distance * Math.sin(theta);
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square of the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     * specified <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @param pt
     *            The specified <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return The square of the distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> to a
     *         specified <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    public double distanceSq(Polar2D pt) {
        double x1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.cos(pt.getTheta());
        double y1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.sin(pt.getTheta());
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a specified point.
     * 
     * @param distance
     *            The distance of the specified point
     * @param theta
     *            The theta angle in radians of the specified point
     * @return The distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and a specified
     *         point.
     */
    public double distance(double distance, double theta) {
        double x1 = distance * Math.cos(theta);
        double y1 = distance * Math.sin(theta);
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance from this <code>Polar2D</code> to a specified
     * <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @param pt
     *            the specified <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return The distance between this <code>Polar2D</code> and the specified
     *         <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    public double distance(Polar2D pt) {
        double x1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.cos(pt.getTheta());
        double y1 = pt.getDistance() * Math.sin(pt.getTheta());
        double x2 = getDistance() * Math.cos(getTheta());
        double y2 = getDistance() * Math.sin(getTheta());
        return Math.sqrt(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new object of the same class and with the same contents as this
     * object.
     * 
     * @return a clone of this instance.
     * @exception OutOfMemoryError
     *                if there is not enough memory.
     * @see java.lang.Cloneable
     * @since 1.7
     */
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the hash code for this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     * 
     * @return a hash code for this <code>Polar2D</code>.
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        long bits = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getDistance());
        bits ^= java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getTheta()) * 31;
        return (((int) bits) ^ ((int) (bits >> 32)));
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether or not two points are equal. Two instances of
     * <code>Polar2D</code> are equal if the values of their <code>x</code> and
     * <code>y</code> member fields, representing their position in the
     * coordinate space, are the same.
     * 
     * @param obj
     *            an object to be compared with this <code>Polar2D</code>
     * @return <code>true</code> if the object to be compared is an instance of
     *         <code>Polar2D</code> and has the same values; <code>false</code>
     *         otherwise.
     * @since 1.7
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Polar2D) {
            Polar2D p2d = (Polar2D) obj;
            return (getDistance() == p2d.getDistance())
                    && (getTheta() == p2d.getTheta());
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Continued in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Continued from the first part of the answer because of an annoying 30,000 character limit on answers.

Here's some code to test the two classes in the first part of the answer.

### CoordinateSystemTester class

```
package com.ggl.game.utilities.swing;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.game.utilities.CoordinateSystem;
import com.ggl.game.utilities.Polar2D;

public class CoordinateSystemTester implements Runnable {

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Coordinate System Tester");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(640, 480);
        mainPanel.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CoordinateSystemTester());
    }

    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1519119839534910933L;

        private CoordinateSystem coordinateSystem;

        private Point pixelPoint;

        private Point2D coordinatePoint;

        private String coordinateString;

        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.coordinateSystem = new CoordinateSystem(25.0D, width, height);
            this.coordinatePoint = new Point2D.Double();
            this.pixelPoint = new Point();
            this.coordinateString = "";

            addComponentListener(new SizeListener());
            addMouseListener(new CoordinateListener());
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }

        public CoordinateSystem getCoordinateSystem() {
            return coordinateSystem;
        }

        public Point2D getCoordinatePoint() {
            return coordinatePoint;
        }

        public void setCoordinatePoint(Point2D coordinatePoint) {
            this.coordinatePoint = coordinatePoint;
        }

        public Point getPixelPoint() {
            return pixelPoint;
        }

        public void setPixelPoint(Point pixelPoint) {
            this.pixelPoint = pixelPoint;
        }

        public void setCoordinateString(String coordinateString) {
            this.coordinateString = coordinateString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString(createLimitsString(), 10, 20);

            drawXAxis(g2d, g);
            drawYAxis(g2d, g);
            drawCoordinate(g2d, g);
        }

        private String createLimitsString() {
            String xs = String.format("%.2f", coordinateSystem.getxLimit());
            String ys = String.format("%.2f", coordinateSystem.getyLimit());

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("The actual limits are (");
            builder.append(xs);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(ys);
            builder.append(")");

            return builder.toString();
        }

        private void drawXAxis(Graphics2D g2d, Graphics g) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0F));
            Point p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-20.0D, 0.0D);
            Point p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(20.0D, 0.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0F));
            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-20.0D, -1.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-20.0D, 1.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            Font font = getFont();
            Point p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-20.0D, -1.0D);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "-20.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-10.0D, -1.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-10.0D, 1.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-10.0D, -1.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "-10.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(10.0D, -1.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(10.0D, 1.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(10.0D, -1.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "10.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(20.0D, -1.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(20.0D, 1.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(20.0D, -1.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "20.0", font);
        }

        private void drawYAxis(Graphics2D g2d, Graphics g) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0F));
            Point p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(0.0D, -20.0D);
            Point p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(0.0D, 20.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0F));
            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-1.0D, -20.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(1.0D, -20.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            Font font = getFont();
            Point p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(3.0D, -20.0D);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "-20.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-1.0D, -10.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(1.0D, -10.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(3.0D, -10.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "-10.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-1.0D, 10.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(1.0D, 10.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(3.0D, 10.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "10.0", font);

            p1 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(-1.0D, 20.0D);
            p2 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(1.0D, 20.0D);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p3 = coordinateSystem.convertPointToPixels(3.0D, 20.0D);
            r = new Rectangle(p3.x - 20, p3.y, 40, 20);
            centerString(g, r, "20.0", font);
        }

        private void drawCoordinate(Graphics2D g2d, Graphics g) {
            if (!coordinateString.equals("")) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fillOval(pixelPoint.x - 5, pixelPoint.y - 5, 10, 10);
                Font font = getFont();
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(pixelPoint.x - 30, pixelPoint.y,
                        60, 20);
                centerString(g, r, coordinateString, font);
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method centers a <code>String</code> in a bounding
         * <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * 
         * @param g
         *            - The <code>Graphics</code> instance.
         * @param r
         *            - The bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * @param s
         *            - The <code>String</code> to center in the bounding
         *            rectangle.
         * @param font
         *            - The display font of the <code>String</code>
         * 
         * @see java.awt.Graphics
         * @see java.awt.Rectangle
         * @see java.lang.String
         */
        private void centerString(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String s, Font font) {
            FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

            Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
            int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
            int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
            int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
            int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

            int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
            int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
        }
    }

    private class CoordinateListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            drawingPanel.setPixelPoint(event.getPoint());
            Point2D coordinatePoint = drawingPanel.getCoordinateSystem()
                    .convertToCartesian(event.getPoint());
            drawingPanel.setCoordinatePoint(coordinatePoint);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                builder.append("(");
                builder.append(String.format("%.2f", coordinatePoint.getX()));
                builder.append(", ");
                builder.append(String.format("%.2f", coordinatePoint.getY()));
                builder.append(")");
            } else if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                Polar2D polarPoint = drawingPanel.getCoordinateSystem()
                        .convertToPolar(event.getPoint());

                builder.append("(");
                builder.append(String.format("%.2f", polarPoint.getDistance()));
                builder.append(", ");
                builder.append(String.format("%.2f",
                        polarPoint.getThetaInDegrees()));
                builder.append(")");
            }

            drawingPanel.setCoordinateString(builder.toString());
            drawingPanel.repaint();
        }

    }

    private class SizeListener extends ComponentAdapter {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            Dimension d = drawingPanel.getSize();
            drawingPanel.getCoordinateSystem().setDrawingSize(d);
            if (!drawingPanel.getPixelPoint().equals(new Point())) {
                Point2D p2d = drawingPanel.getCoordinatePoint();
                Point p = drawingPanel.getCoordinateSystem().convertToPixels(
                        p2d);
                drawingPanel.setPixelPoint(p);
            }
            drawingPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```